# Replace \ into // using gsub in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am trying to replace `x` variable data   `E:\testCSV.csv` to `E://testCSV.csv` using `gsub` function..

```
> x
[1] "E:\testCSV.csv"
> gsub("\", "//", x, fixed = TRUE)
Error: unexpected '/' in "gsub("\", "//"
```

tried all combinations of escape strings, including brackets `[]` with no success.
Please suggest

Answer (score 4):

We may need

```
sub("^([^:]+\\:).(.*)", "\\1//t\\2", str1)
#[1] "E://testCSV.csv"
```

The reason it is not working is because `t` is escaped i.e. it represents for tab (`\t`).  To check it, we can use `cat`.

```
cat(str1, sep="\n")
#E:      estCSV.csv
```

Usually, we cannot create a string with a single `\` in R if it doesn't have any meaning.

```
str2 <- "E:\zestCV.csv"
#Error: '\z' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""E:\z"
```

We need to escape it with a second `\`.

```
str2 <- "E:\\zestCV.csv"
str2
#[1] "E:\\zestCV.csv"
```

To replace that, the method showed by the OP (slightly different) should work.

```
sub("\\\\", "//", str2)
#[1] "E://zestCV.csv"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "E:\testCSV.csv"
```

Comment: it is a nice solution but I am straggling with regular expression symbols to be used for sub or gsub, is there any place that I can learn them? I have read many stuff on web but non was helpful

Comment: @Learner I guess [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html) is the link that should help.  However, we need to practise it.  Create some challenging strings and try to extract some patterns out of it.  During the course of solving it, you will also learn..